# Is there a specified way to transform int to str in nltk module?

Tags: python, nltk

My 1st time here!

I think I got a trouble in my code, could you help me?

The point is, I created a function with `nltk` module and I don't know where I'm going wrong when it reports me that errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-7fe386d50c39> in <module>
----> 1 frasescomstemming = fazstemmer(base)

<ipython-input-93-e5451b452b6b> in fazstemmer(texto)
      7     for (palavras, emocao) in texto:
      8         comstemming = [str(stemmer.stem(p))
----> 9                        for p in palavras.split() if p not in stopwords]
     10         frasessstemming.append((comstemming, emocao))
     11     return frasessstemming

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Here is my code:

```
def fazstemmer(texto):
stemmer = nltk.stem.RSLPStemmer()
frasessstemming = []
for (palavras, emocao) in texto:
    comstemming = [str(stemmer.stem(p))
                   for p in palavras.split() if p not in stopwords]
    frasessstemming.append((comstemming, emocao))
return frasessstemming
```

Comment: Do you have an example input for `texto`?

Comment: here is the example:

base = df.values.tolist()

the data frame has two coluns, with the comment as str and emotion, also as str.

Answer (score 1):

As for **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'** This should be caused by `for p in palavras.split() if p not in stopwords]` You can change the type of palavras in the last loop.

```
def fazstemmer(texto):
    stemmer = nltk.stem.RSLPStemmer()
    frasessstemming = []
    for (palavras, emocao) in texto:
        comstemming = str(stemmer.stem(p))
        palavras = str(palavras)
        for p in palavras.split():
            if p not in stopwords:
                frasessstemming.append((comstemming, emocao))
    return frasessstemming
```

Answer (score 0):

Without an example input `texto` and desired output, it's hard to guess what's the data structure / type of the variables, so here's a guess.

Try this:

```py
stemmer = nltk.stem.RSLPStemmer()

def fazstemmer(text):
    for words, emotion in text:
        words, emotion = str(words), str(emotion)
        for word in words.split():
            if word not in stopwords:
                yield stemmer.stem(word), emotion
                
stemmed_text = list(fazstemmer(text))
```